# Отношения Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Нубский вопрос. Есть 4 таблицы БД: articles, tags, articles_tags, authors.

Есть контроллер статей:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Article;
use App\Author;
use App\Tag;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::where('active', 1)->orderBy('created_at')->paginate(5);

    foreach ($articles as $article) {
        $authors = Author::find($article->author_id);
    }

    $tags = $articles->tags();

    // dd($articles);

    return view('pages.articles', ['articles' => $articles, 'authors' => $authors, 'tags' => $tags]);
}
}
```

Есть модель Tag.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    public static function articles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article');
}
}
```

Есть модель Article.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{

public static function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
}
}
```

Есть вьюха:

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
<article class="row article-block">

    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <time class="icon">
          <em>{{ Date::parse($article->created_at)->format('l') }}</em>
          <strong>{{ Date::parse($article->created_at)->format('F') }}</strong>
          <span>{{ Date::parse($article->created_at)->format('j') }}</span>
        </time>
        <div>
            {{ Date::parse($article->created_at)->format('F') }} {{ Date::parse($article->created_at)->format('Y') }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ Date::parse($article->created_at)->format('j') }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> {{ $article->view }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="{{ $article->author_id }}">{{ $authors->firstName }} {{ $authors->lastName }}</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            @foreach($tags as $tag)
                {{ $tag->name }},
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

В итоге выдает

```
FatalErrorException in ArticleController.php line 27:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::tags()
```

Задача стоит, что вывести статьи, их теги и авторов. Laravel только учу, подскажите как правильно составить запросы для вывода всей информации? Спасибо!

Comment: articles_tags
http://i.piccy.info/i9/bfcdabeeac21975d149d989fc24e4e58/1446458112/51889/966787/Articles_Tags.png
articles
http://i.piccy.info/i9/3ae043a007d41d52c3eb7e06a35e2719/1446457903/135855/966787/Articles.png
tags
http://i.piccy.info/i9/b10f7621a4f8b1241af7e3abce46e3b4/1446457890/70549/966787/Tags.png
authors
http://i.piccy.info/i9/ca6f50566e2b8091227ea11bc5f646ba/1446458319/90237/966787/Authors.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$articles = Article::where('active', 1)->orderBy('created_at')->paginate(5);
```

метод `paginate()` собирает коллецию, тогда как для выполнения

```
$articles->tags();
```

нужен `Builder`.

Вообще все можно сделать в разы проще

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
     $articles = Article::with('author', 'tags')->where('active', 1)->orderBy('created_at')->paginate(5);
     return view('pages.articles', array('articles' => $articles));
  }
}
```

Article

```
class Article extends Model
{

  public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
  } 

  public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
  } 
}
```

Во вьюхе получение идет через `$article->author` и `$article->tags`

Comment: Не сработало :(

Comment: FatalErrorException in Article.php line 15:
Using $this when not in object context

Comment: не заметила static, теперь должно работать

Comment: Да, это оно. Спасибо огромное за помощь!

Comment: Добрый вечер, есть вопрос по правке: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/42845. Если к laravel не относится, может и из заголовка вырезать его?